HTML Link in Annotorious / JSON W3 Annotiations
I'm working with annotorious annotations in an openseadragon project.
I want to add HTML links to the annotations, but fail to find a way to properly format them as the <a href> tags and all other HTML tags are always shown in plain text instead of interpreted as HTML.
My JSON Annotations code looks like this:
 "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/anno.jsonld",
    "type": "Annotation",
    "body": [{
        "type" : "TextualBody",
        "value": "BLACK HOLE<br><br>Annotation text<br><br><a href='HTTPLINKTOOURDATABASE'>DATABASE</a>",
        "format" : "text/html",
    }],
    "target": {
        "selector": {
            "type": "SvgSelector",
            "value": "<svg><polygon points=\"32274.7,30673 32088.3,30673 31783.2,30678.6 31372.4,30815.4 30841.8,31160.4 30438.2,31508 29927.5,31785.2 29164,32046.5 28897.8,32083.4 28976.6,32527.3 29443.2,32666.8 30157.2,32765.5 30648.5,32770.2 \"></polygon></svg>"
        }
    },

I worked my way around this manual https://www.w3.org/TR/annotation-model/, specified the fomat as "text/html" to no avail.
Any help is highly appreciated! THANKS A LOT!

I don't know the answer. Have you tried asking here? https://github.com/annotorious/annotorious-openseadragon/issues
